# Overriding equals in Java - getClass() approach

Tags: java, overriding, equals, equality

In the post [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) one explains in great detail how to write proper equality method in Java using getClass to compare RUntime types of two objects we equate. I understand that the reason we do this is to make sure that if B extends A we want a.equals(b) = b.equals(a) (reflexivity).

It does provide a big limitation in my opinion. If you have a collection of objects A, inswert a few B objects as they are subclasses of A, then a.equals(b) is always false... Perhaps, at certain times, we should stick to the old `instanceof` operator to provide polymorphism and allow equality of subtypes? What are your thoughts?

Comment: ...Yes.  What you're saying is quite clearly true.  What's the problem?

Comment: I do not any specific problem, I was wondering whether one practice would be always favoured and whether I was missing an important point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only look as far as `java.util` to see examples of where `.equals()` gets redefined to care only about interface. For example, [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), where the relevant characteristics equality is defined, and the formula for calculating the hash code is explicitly documented.

So to answer your question, yes -- ignoring subtypes makes sense under certain circumstances. But I like Josh Bloch's approach to this by making an interface the aspect of equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily the case. For example, if you look at the collections in the JDK, they use a less strict definition for equality. The code below outputs "true" twice. In the end, it is a matter of contract and documentation.

[`equals` contract in List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (emphasis mine):

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. **This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.**

Note that it does not breach the reflexivity requirement as long as **all** the classes that implement `List` respect that contract.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("a");

    List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();
    list2.add("a");

    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("a");

    System.out.println("arraylist = linkedlist? " + list1.equals(list2));
    System.out.println("arraylist = Arrays.aslit? " + list1.equals(list3));
}
```